# Disable auto conda activation of a non-base env, which occurs only in VSCode, not in command prompt

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, conda, miniconda, vscode-remote

I am using the Remote Explorer extension in VSCode to access my university HPC, which is Linux. I have miniconda installed in my HPC directory. Whenver I access HPC through VSCode, I am automatically directed to a virtual environment named R4.3.2 which I created previously. However, such auto activation does not occur when I type win+R, cmd, then ssh @.

Here is my .bashrc file

```
# .bashrc
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi
# Source global definitions

# User specific environment
export PATH="/storage/***Lab/***/bin":$PATH

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/storage/***Lab/sharedata/softwares/libevent_v2.1.12_d20210816/lib":$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/storage/***Lab/***/sft/R-4.3.3/lib64/R/lib":$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/***Lab/***/lib/local_imagemagick/sft/lib":$LD_LIBRARY_PATH


export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/home/***Lab/***/lib/pkgconfig":"/storage/***Lab/***/sft/libtiff/lib/pkgconfig"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:"/home/***Lab/***/lib/local_imagemagick/sft/lib/pkgconfig"


export R_LIBS="/storage/***Lab/***/sft/R-4.3.3/lib64/R/library"


# User specific aliases and functions
alias cdh="cd /storage/***Lab/***"


# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/***Lab/***/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/***Lab/***/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/***Lab/***/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/***Lab/***/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Here is my .bash_profile:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Here is my .zshrc file:

```
#
# .zshrc is sourced in interactive shells.
# It should contain commands to set up aliases,
# functions, options, key bindings, etc.
#

autoload -U compinit
compinit

#allow tab completion in the middle of a word
setopt COMPLETE_IN_WORD

## keep background processes at full speed
#setopt NOBGNICE
## restart running processes on exit
#setopt HUP

## history
#setopt APPEND_HISTORY
## for sharing history between zsh processes
#setopt INC_APPEND_HISTORY
#setopt SHARE_HISTORY

## never ever beep ever
#setopt NO_BEEP

## automatically decide when to page a list of completions
#LISTMAX=0

## disable mail checking
#MAILCHECK=0

# autoload -U colors
#colors

# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/***Lab/***/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/***Lab/***/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/***Lab/***/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/***Lab/***/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

I tried to add `conda deactivate` to .bashrc and .zshrc, but the virtual environment is still auto activated when I use VScode to access HPC.

Here is the setttings.json file for my vscode:

```
{
  //###########################################################################
  // Path
  //###########################################################################
  // Path to R in linux
  "r.rpath.linux": "/storage/***Lab/***/sft/R-4.3.3/bin/R",
  "r.rterm.linux": "/storage/***Lab/***/sft/R-4.3.3/bin/R",

  // Path to Python
  "[python]": {
    "editor.formatOnType": true
  },
  "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\Users\\***\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\python.exe",

  //###########################################################################
  // Formatting
  //###########################################################################

  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  //"editor.wordWrap": "wordWrapColumn",
  "editor.fontSize": 16,
  "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt", //Terminal default to cmd.

  "r.bracketedPaste": true,
  "r.sessionWatcher": true,
  "[r]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "REditorSupport.r"
  },

  // Vertical ruler
  "editor.rulers": [80],
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorRuler.foreground": "#5a626b"
  },

  // Not having to manually select platform during remote access.
  // Idea from https://www.cnblogs.com/jhj117/p/14520060.html and
  // https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh
  "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {
    "1**.**.**.***" (IP address): "linux"
  },
  "terminal.integrated.enableMultiLinePasteWarning": false,
  "r.plot.useHttpgd": true,
  "vsicons.dontShowNewVersionMessage": true,
  "update.mode": "manual"
}
```

I want to know why this auto activate of a particular non-base env occurs and why it only occurs when using vscode but not when accessing HPC through command prompt and ssh. How to disable such auto activation when using vscode?